# Need qpid-proton publish/subscribe amqp sample program for python to access Azure topic

Tags: python-2.7, azure, amqp, azureservicebus, qpid

I am using Azure cloud service bus to send and receive messages using AMQP protocol. I have installed proton-c libraries in my debian-linux. I tried the below program to send and receive message from the queue. My requirement is instead of queue I have use topics. Please anyone give me a sample program to use topics in Azure cloud.

```
import sys, optparse
from proton import *

messenger = Messenger()
message = Message()
message.address = "amqps://owner:<<key>>@namespace.servicebus.windows.net/queuename"
message.body = "sending message to the queue"
messenger.put(message)
messenger.send()
```

Instead of queuename in above url if I give the topic name then the program running forever. Please someone help me. I am new to python programming.

Comment: Can anyone quickly tell, i can use AMQP protocol to send message to topics in Azure using python? There is no samples available. I searched in the Web for the past one week, not able to find the samples.

Answer (score 2):

I found myself the solution for this problem. I guess very few people are working in Azure Cloud so I didn't get any answers.

Here is the solution:

If we create topics in Azure service bus, it always select the checkbox "Enable Partitioning". AMQP protocol doesn't support partitioning topics/queues so I stuck with above issue. Once I deleted the topic and recreate the same topic without select the checkbox "Enable Partitioning". Its work fine. :)